# Google Sheet Challenge Importrange + Substitute or Index Filter + Substitute

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do `IMPORTRANGE` + `SUBSTITUTE`, but so far it has been a failure. I tried to import a column from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1. However, in that column there is a "-" symbol which I want to replace with 0.

I tried using this formula but it says formula error

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL", "NAME!J7:J"), "select Col1", 0), "-", ""))
```

But now everything is either 0 or blank now.

Answer (score 1):

Assumning you are importing from within the same spreadsheet, try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(NAME!J7:J, "-", ))
```

and see if that helps. If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we have some data to work with.

EDIT: Change your formula in C1
to

```
=ArrayFormula({""; "Country Be"; ""; SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4CMmottwETd4XzwhvKSyGbLXusntJQzAV_FWbkLfaI/edit#gid=80375123", "Raw!C4:C"), "-",0)+0})
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Hi JPV thank your reply, it is actually from another sheet. Here is a copy of my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JWLkrSdndHYJYvhAPo-jyXNGWqOoDdBBXf7-ZzO4YrA/edit#gid=80375123

Basically I imported a data from a different sheet but I want to replace - with 0. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Update my answer. See if that helps?